# \pagenumbering{roman} prints uppercase roman numbers in report class

Tags: page-numbering, report, roman-numerals, spanish

I'm writing a report class document. I want some pages at the beginning of the document to be numbered with roman lowercase numbers and the rest with arabic numbers. I used `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` at the desired locations. These codes worked well except that `\pagenumbering{roman}` prints uppercase roman numbers and not lowercase roman numbers. What's going wrong? (I'm a newbie here and also a non-native english speaker, so please excuse me if my question is not correctly stated.) Thanks!

A MWE (not so 'minimal'; I show the preamble in full in case the problem is there):

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[hypcap,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\en}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\de}{\colon}
\newcommand{\id}{\textup{id}}

\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{coro}[teo]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{lema}[teo]{Lema}
\newtheorem{prop}[teo]{Proposici\'on}
\newtheorem{conj}[teo]{Conjetura}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}[teo]{Definici\'on}
\newtheorem{ejer}{Ejercicio}
\newtheorem{ejm}{Ejemplo}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{obs}[teo]{Observaci\'on}

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\vspace*{0.5cm}

A rather long and complex title...

\afterpage{\blankpage}
\end{titlepage}

\afterpage{\blankpage}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{flushright}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}

To some special person\\[50pt]

\vspace*{\fill}
\clearpage
\afterpage{\blankpage}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}

Nice quote

\end{flushright}


\vspace*{\fill}
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent {\large \bf Acknowledgments}\newline
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}

Text

\vspace*{\fill}\newpage\null\newpage


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{First chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Normally `\pagenumbering{roman}` doesn't do that, unless there is some code changing that behaviour. Please show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Hi! I edited the post, adding a mwe.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot to find the problem. As a tip for your next question, you could try to reduce the mwe even further by removing packages one by one until you narrow down the issue to the minimum number of packages. For instance, I found the problem by removing the bottom half of the packages, theorem definitions, and custom commands, and then proceeded removing packages until all that was left was `babel`. From there on a quick look at the documentation showed the solution :-)

Comment: Oh, sorry :S. I will follow your recommendation next time! Thanks again.

Comment: No problem at all, it's just a tip :-) The thing is that most of the times (for me at least) when narrowing down the issue to ask a question here I end up finding the problem myself. Some times it saves you a great deal of trouble :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not actually an uppercase roman numeral, but a small caps roman numeral. This feature is triggered by the `spanish` babel. The following is enough to reproduce the issue:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
hello I \makeatletter\@roman\c@page
\end{document}
```

output:

> [image]

Section [**1.3 Modifiers**](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf#subsection.1.3) of the `babel` manual shows that you can use the `lcroman` modifier for the `spanish` language to change that behaviour:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish.lcroman]{babel}
\begin{document}
hello I \makeatletter\@roman\c@page
\end{document}
```

and the output:

> [image]

Note, however, that the [`spanish-babel`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/spanish/spanish.pdf#subsection.2.2) package warns you that lowercase roman numerals are an ortographic error in Spanish:

> [image: <code>es-lcroman</code> - Opción de paquete: Como último recurso, de haber problemas con el valor predeterminado o con <code>es-ucroman</code>, con esta opción de paquete puede dejarse la definición de LaTeX, aunque en español los romanos en minúscula sean una falta ortográfica.]

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!!